# How to fetch Entity in Spring data jpa with @EntityGraph by default?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

FetchType eager has N+1 problem, Entity graph works as expected, but how can I make an Entity to always load with EntityGraph without having to put @EntityGraph annotation over each method?

Here is the example, when I load the restaurant Entity ( some methods, fields are omitted for brevity ) I have everything done in a single query because of NamedEntityGraph.

```
 @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @NamedEntityGraph(name = GRAPH_RESTAURANT_WITH_VOTES, attributeNodes =
                    @NamedAttributeNode("votes"))
    public class Restaurant extends AbstractNamedEntity {
        public static final String GRAPH_RESTAURANT_WITH_VOTES = "Restaurant with dishes-votes.Graph";
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        @JsonManagedReference
        private List<Vote> votes;
```

Here is a fetching.

```
 @EntityGraph(GRAPH_RESTAURANT_WITH_VOTES)
    @Query("SELECT r FROM Restaurant r ORDER BY r.name")
    List<Restaurant> findAll();
```

Vote side of the relationship:

```
  @Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Vote extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Restaurant restaurant;
// extra fields, methods
}
```

When I have the same code but without @Query (use default Spring data jpa findAll() ), @EntityGraph and  FetchType=Eager included ( like that )

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Vote> votes;
```

I load a restaurant with a single query and then for every restaurant I have an extra query to load a Vote.

Comment: Could you clarify in which scenario eager loading has an N+1 problem while eager loading via entity graph hasn't?

Comment: @JensSchauder I've added some details.